# Implementing a List data structure in java

Tags: java, list, data-structures

I have a homework about implementing lists in java. I have written a code, and a method about displaying the elements, but when I run it, it says there is an error in this method. can you please help me fix this?

here is my code:

```
public class Lista {

    public int num;
    public Lista pas;

    public Lista(int num){
        this.num = num;
    }

    public void display(){
        System.out.println(num);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        linkedList l = new linkedList();
        l.insertfirst(1);
        l.insertfirst(3);
        l.insertfirst(5);
        l.display();
    }
}

class linkedList{
    public Lista LIST;
    public Lista pozicion;

    linkedList(){
        LIST = null;
    }

    public void insert(int num, Lista pozicion){
        Lista temp = pozicion.pas;
        Lista l = new Lista(num);
        pozicion.pas.num = num;
        pozicion.pas.pas = temp;
    }

    public void delete(Lista pozicion){
        pozicion.pas = pozicion.pas.pas;
    }

    public Lista locate(int num, Lista LIST){
        pozicion = LIST;
        while (pozicion.pas != null){
            if (pozicion.pas.num == num){
                return pozicion;
            }else{
                pozicion = pozicion.pas;
            }
        }

        return pozicion;
    }

    public void insertfirst(int num){
        Lista eRe = new Lista(num);
        eRe.pas = LIST;
        LIST = eRe;
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method display() is undefined for the type linkedList

 at Lista.main(Lista.java:24)

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method display() is undefined for the type linkedList

 at Lista.main(Lista.java:24)

Comment: Pretty descriptive error, if you ask me. Your `linkedList` class doesn't declare a method `display()`.

Comment: shmosel is right. Unfortunately, it's unclear what the fix should be, because the design of the classes is very weird, and OP's intentions are unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for starters...

display() is not a method of class linkedList (note: naming convention should be LinkedList).

display() is a method of Lista. That is why the IDE is telling you '**display() is undefined for the type linkedList**'

Just quickly looking at your code for what you need to do... **You need to implement a get()** (or perhaps a solution to get the first element of the linkedList and from there iterate through the linkedList) **method in the linkedList class which returns a Lista object. With that Lista object, you can then call the method .display() on it.**